# MongoDb isDeleted attribute - not always exist

Tags: mongodb

When fetching records in mongoDb using QueryBuilder:

```
DBObject query = QueryBuilder.start("field1).is("foo").and("field2").is("bar").get();
```

Sometimes isDeleted attribute will be on the record,
But sometimes it will not be there,
How do I use QueryBuilder to tell MongoDb to fetch records where isDeleted attribute is not true, or not there..

Using expressions I can do:

```
        myOr.add(new BasicDBObject("isDeleted", bool));
        myOr.add(new BasicDBObject("isDeleted", new BasicDBObject("$exists", bool)));
        DBObject query = baseFilter.append("$or", myOr);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially want the following mongodb query

```
var query = {
    "$or": [
        { "isDeleted": false },
        { "isDeleted": { "$exists": false } }
    ]
}
db.collection.find(query)
```

Using the **[`QueryBuilder`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.2/com/mongodb/QueryBuilder.html)**, this will translate to

```
QueryBuilder query = new QueryBuilder();
query.or(
    QueryBuilder.start("isDeleted").is(false).get(),
    QueryBuilder.start("isDeleted").exists(false).get()
);

DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query.get());
```